# How to configure Emotion js with Vite 4 in React TypeScript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, emotion, emotion-js

I am migrating from Webpack to Vite in my React Typescript app.

I try to get [Emotion js](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) to work.

```
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
"vite": "^4.3.9",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
```

Its compiling client after `npm start` but I got the following error:

> [vite] warning: The JSX factory cannot be set when using React's
> "automatic" JSX transform 1  |  import RefreshRuntime from
> "/@react-refresh";const inWebWorker = typeof WorkerGlobalScope !==
> 'undefined' && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope;let
> prevRefreshReg;let prevRefreshSig;if (import.meta.hot && !inWebWorker)
> {  if (!window.**vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed**) {    throw
> new Error(      "@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something
> is wrong. " +      "See
> [https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201"](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201%22)
> );  }  prevRefreshReg = window.$RefreshReg$;  prevRefreshSig =
> window.$RefreshSig$;  window.$RefreshReg$ = (type, id) => {
> RefreshRuntime.register(type,

My steps to add Emotion to Vite:

1. Add this rule to `.eslintrc.cjs`:

`"rules": { "react/no-unknown-property": ['error', { ignore: ['css'] }] }`

2. Add to `tsconfig.json`:
   `"types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client", "@emotion/react/types/css-prop"],`

3. Add to Vite config `vite.config.ts`:

   `export default defineConfig({ plugins: [ react({ jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react', }),`

In my React component I still get:

> 'jsx' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { RTLLogo } from 'app/components/atoms/icons';
import { HomePage } from 'app/routes/paths';

import Styles from './Logo.styles';
import { Props } from './Logo.types';

const MyComponent = ({ classes }: Props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const styles = Styles({ theme, classes });

  return (
    <Link to={HomePage} css={styles.root}>
      <Logo />
    </Link>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it with a little bit different setup:

- Step 2: Instead of `"types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client", "@emotion/react/types/css-prop"` add `"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"` to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  },
  ...
}
```

- Step 3: Your `vite.config.ts` file seems to be correct. As per [this comment](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2523#issuecomment-1076327127), the `@jsx` pragma solution and `jsxImportSource` are interchangable, so feel free to replace

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
```

with the following

```
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
```

Note: I am using Typescript `v5.1.3`